# Adding a Style for a given Time in a element in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a classname in a button for 1000ms and then remove it.
I am trying to change it in a function so I am not able to use useState and useEffect.

```
const highlight = (id) => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }

  const gambleHandler = () => {
    const startTime = new Date().getTime();
    let finalGhost = null;
    while (new Date().getTime() - startTime < 1000) {
      let randomGhost =
        chosenList[Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenList.length)];
      // const element = document.getElementById(randomGhost.id);
      setTimeout(() => {highlight(randomGhost.id)},20);
      clearTimeout();
      // console.log(randomGhost);
      finalGhost  = randomGhost;
    }
    console.log(finalGhost);
  };
```

```
<div className={styles.fleft}>
        {chosenList.map((ghost) => (
          <button
            id={ghost.id}
            key={ghost.id}
            onClick={() => subGhostHandler(ghost.id)}
          >
            {ghost.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
```

```
 <Button disabled={flag2} buttonName="GAMBLE" onClick={gambleHandler}/>
```

Comment: You should work with state here ... see this Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-82zhgh